# Duplicate values in a datagridview using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, indexing, datagridview, duplicates

I need to search for duplicate entries in a datagridview column (ex:itemcode) using vb.net ,and then I want to retrieve its row index so that I can combine those entries. 
My code below can only check for the duplicate if exists however I need to know the index.

```
 Public Function Is_Duplicate_Grid(ByVal itemcode As long) As Boolean
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
            If row.Cells("ItemCode").Value = itemcode Then
                Return True
            End If
            Return False
        Next
  End Function
```

Comment: is the DGV bound to something or did you populate it manually?

Comment: i populated it manually and at the end when i wanna save the results i wanna check for duplicates

Comment: iam working on a receipt bro

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict`, you are comparing an object to string...Also if you want to return the index your function isn't doing that... How about a function that takes a `DataGridView`, the column and what you want to check and return a `List(Of Integer)` which would be the index's of all the same items...

Comment: yeah sure, could you provide an example on how to do that please ? :D

Comment: Yes, sure just a minute about done.

Comment: check this but its not 100% working :                                                              For intI As Integer = 0 To idgv.Rows.Count - 1
            For intJ As Integer = 0 To idgv.Rows.Count - 1
                If idgv.Rows(intI).Cells("Code").Value = _
                   idgv.Rows(intJ).Cells("Code").Value And _
                   intI <> intJ Then
                    MessageBox.Show(intI & "   " & intJ)
                    idgv.Rows(intJ).Cells(3).Value += CInt(idgv.Rows(intI).Cells(3).Value)



                End If

            Next

        Next

Comment: @charles please see answer, if it helps please accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into `Linq` which can be useful in this situation...

**My Recommendation**

```
Public Shared Function DuplicateGridIndex(ByVal _DataGridView As DataGridView, ByVal ColumnName As String, ByVal ItemCode As Long) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim nList As New List(Of Integer)
    Try
        If _DataGridView IsNot Nothing AndAlso _DataGridView.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso ColumnName IsNot Nothing AndAlso _DataGridView.Columns.Contains(ColumnName) Then
            nList = _DataGridView.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Where(Function(t) t.Cells(ColumnName).Value IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso t.Cells(ColumnName).Value = ItemCode).Select(Function(r) r.Cells(ColumnName).RowIndex).ToList
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return nList
    End Try

    Return nList
End Function
```

**Explanation**

- Make sure we have the `DataGridView`, column we will search and the value to look for.
- Cast all rows as an array where the `cells.value` is not `DBNull.Value` and finally where that cells value is equal to our search value passed into the function we are looking for.

**Short example usage**

```
    Dim Dups As New List(Of Integer)
    Dups = DuplicateGridIndex(Me.DataGridView1, "ItemCode", 1432)

    If Dups.Count > 0 Then
        'Do what you need with each of the index's
    End If
```

**Your Original Modified (no error checking, nulls, column check etc...)**

```
 Public Function Is_Duplicate_Grid(ByVal itemcode As Long) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim nList As New List(Of Integer)

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells("ItemCode").Value = itemcode Then
            nList.Add(row.Index)
        End If
    Next

    Return nList
End Function
```

Comment: i would like to combine every duplicated entry

Answer (score 1):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        If i <> j Then
            If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("column_name").Value =   DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells("column_name").Value then
DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
            end if
        end if
    next
next
```

Comment: Some explanation of the code would improve the answer.